# Scrolling Richtextblock in ContentDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

In my UWP application I've got a RichTextBlock inside ContentDialog and I set some sample Height for each element to check if it works or not.

I'm sure content inside RichTextBlock is taller than height=100 but I can't scroll up or down!!

How can I fix it?

```
<ContentDialog ...>
 <ScrollViewer  Height="100">
    <StackPanel Height="100">
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="richBox" Height="100">
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>Release info:</Bold>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[1]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>A commentary by:</Bold>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[2]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>details:</Bold>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[3]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
</ContentDialog>
```

[image: Contentdialog can't scroll]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `Height` definitions in your `StackPanel` and `RichTextBlock`.

```
<ContentDialog ...>
 <ScrollViewer Height="100">
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="richBox">
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>Release info:</Bold>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[1]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>A commentary by:</Bold>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[2]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>details:</Bold>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{x:Bind txt[3]}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
</ContentDialog>
```

If the child has the exact same height as the parent `ScrollViewer`, then the latter has no need to scroll so the scroll bar won't be provided. Generally you don't need to specify for `ScrollViewer`'s child element - when the child element is taller than the `ScrollViewer`, the scroll bar will show; otherwise it won't.

Comment: The provide solution doesn't work. I have tried it and the ScrollViewer doesn't scroll the contents of the RichTexBlock. I've tried with even simpler code.

Comment: <ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialog">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
                <Button>Hola</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </ContentDialog>

Comment: Yes it **does**. Your example is missing a `Height` on your `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: I don't want to have a fixed Height. My ScrollBar should expand automatically (vertically) to fit the container. Please, refer to this question in which the XAML is clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629437/contentdialog-in-uwp-bad-scrolling-behavior

Comment: Sorry, but I have to add that there should be a solution. What happens if the contents don't fit the size of the ContentDialog? A ContentDialog doesn't inherently have a permanent size. You can resize the owner, and you want your contents to resize as well. Isn't it reasonable?